# Laravel Redis class not found in sail installation

Tags: php, laravel, docker, phpredis

I discovered an issue with our Laravel project during a fresh installation. When I cloned the entire project and created the env file, I proceeded to install Sail containers and the existing Composer package file by executing the following command as per the official Sail documentation:

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v "$(pwd):/var/www/html" \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php82-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

After running the above command, I encountered this error message:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Error

  Class "Redis" not found

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:81
     77▕      * @throws \LogicException
     78▕      */
     79▕     protected function createClient(array $config)
     80▕     {
  ➜  81▕         return tap(new Redis, function ($client) use ($config) {
     82▕             if ($client instanceof RedisFacade) {
     83▕                 throw new LogicException(
     84▕                     extension_loaded('redis')
     85▕                         ? 'Please remove or rename the Redis facade alias in your "app" configuration file in order to avoid collision with the PHP Redis extension.'

      +19 vendor frames

  20  [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeServiceProvider))
      +5 vendor frames

  26  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I suspect that laravelsail/phpxx-composer image does not have the Redis extension installed, but I'm unsure how to address this issue.

For reference, the Laravel version is v10, we are using phpredis, and our PHP version is v8.2.

Comment: It should; do `sail tinker` and put `extension_loaded('redis')` in it to check. See https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/302 for a discussion of a similar issue in 8.0/8.1.

Comment: added to the composer.json?
"require": {
     
        "predis/predis": "^2.0",
},

Comment: @ceejayoz  There is no container to check. It is just laravelsail/phpxx-composer.  Nothing created yet

Comment: @ЛюбомирГорбей as I mentioned I'm using phpredis. Should i require predis package?

Comment: try:
 docker run --rm -p 6379:6379 redis .
 Should i require predis package? -Yes

Comment: @ЛюбомирГорбей Maybe I didn't mentioned it correctly. There are no containers. I'm trying to install a fresh clone of that project. There is just laravelsail/phpxx-composer container which is the official suggestion to install composer packages and that's where I catched the error.

Comment: > `which is the official suggestion to install composer packages and that's where I catched the error` ===>>> do a little more than the official stuff. Everyone is talking about running containers, so `docker-compose up -d` your containers. Publish sail's vendor libraries which will give you a nice docker-compose.ymlm get more containers going than just that single php container. You need the phpredis package to access `redis` ... containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.env` file breaks the installation. [They intended](https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/302#issuecomment-997219320) this command to be run on clear repo clone where `.env` file should not be committed as a good practice. To install vendor packages you don't need this configuration, just like `--ignore-platform-reqs` skips all extensions checks on Laravel side config cannot rely on them (here Redis) either.

IMO simplest fix is to add `-e "CACHE_DRIVER=file" \` to the docker command that you took from Laravel docs:

```bash
docker run --rm \
    -e "CACHE_DRIVER=file" \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v "$(pwd):/var/www/html" \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php82-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Your millage may vary. If you use other config options / deps, they may need additional configuration resets. With long list of those you may consider `--env-file` docker options to provide an empty file